# Get object parameter's name in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, el

I'm very very new to JSP we've just started getting classes on it this week. I'm running into a problem for an assignment I need to finish for school.

```jsp
<c:forEach var="tempGebruiker" items="${gebruikers}">
    <!-- Per gebruiker wordt nu een rij aangemaakt met daarin zijn gegevens -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            ${tempGebruiker.name}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${tempGebruiker.streetAddress}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${tempGebruiker.huisnummer}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${tempGebruiker.city}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${tempGebruiker.rol}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="gebruikers/wijzig?id=${tempGebruiker.customerNumber}">Wijzig</a> |
            <a href="javascript:if(confirm('Weet u het zeker dat u deze gebruiker wil verwijderen?'))
               window.location='gebruikers/verwijder?id=${tempGebruiker.customerNumber}';">Verwijder</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

In this part:

```jsp
<td>
    ${tempGebruiker.rol}
</td>
```

A role object is returned, though instead i need it to display the name of that object. As follows: `tempGebruiker.getRol().getName();`
How would I achieve this using EL?

Edit:
Role bean

```
    public class Role implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

User bean

```
    public class User implements Serializable {

    private long customerNumber;
    private String name;
    private String streetAddress;
    private String city;
    private int huisnummer;
    private Role rol;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(long customerNumber, String naam, String straatnaam, int huisnummer, String stad, Role rol) {
        this.setCustomerNumber(customerNumber);
        this.setName(naam);
        this.setStreetAddress(straatnaam);
        this.setCity(stad);
        this.setHuisnummer(huisnummer);
        this.setRol(rol);
    }

    /* Getters en setters voor de verschillende attributen van het Model */
    public long getCustomerNumber() {
        return customerNumber;
    }

    public Role getRol() {
        return rol;
    }

    public void setRol(Role rol) {
        this.rol = rol;
    }

    public int getHuisnummer() {
        return huisnummer;
    }

    public void setHuisnummer(int huisnummer) {
        this.huisnummer = huisnummer;
    }

    public void setCustomerNumber(long customerNumber) {
        if (customerNumber < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Customer number may not be negative, value = " + customerNumber);
        }
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Customer name may not be empty");
        }
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStreetAddress() {
        return streetAddress;
    }

    public void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress) {
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried: tempGebruiker.rol.name ??

Comment: @Taerus, how is Rol defined? I mean its structure

Comment: @spoko Your edit is invalid. JSP stands for Java Server Pages, that's nothing to do with Javascript, and removing the Java tag is incorrect. Please be more careful when submitting tag edits next time.

Comment: The tag 'Java' in this case, might be removed as well. If I had asked this question, I would **not** have tagged  'Java' to this question, since there is no Java SE problem which could otherwise be reproduced by simply using the `main()` method. @Unihedron

Comment: @Tiny While the existence of tag [[tag:java]] is debatable, removing it with the comment "_Javascript != Java_" is not.

Comment: Can u give the out put of <td>
    ${tempGebruiker.rol}
</td> in jsp. as u mention it's return Role object, but what it is display on screen. can u provide that.

Answer (score 0):

```
${tempGebruiker.rol.name}
```

The getters `getXxx()` or (boolean) `isXxx` will be turned into a selector `.xxx`.

You can also use methods:

```
${tempGebruikder.isInRole('Admin')}
```

---

***After comment:***

You seem to have tried the right thing, maybe compare my "solution" below on the beans:

```
public class Gebruiker {
    public Role getRol() {
        return "actor";
    }
}
public class Role {
    public String getName() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

You might try:

```
<td>XXX <c:out value="${tempGebruiker.rol}" escapeXml="true"/> YYY</td>
```

- Markers XXX, YYY to search it in the HTML source text.
- c:out with escapeXml to translate `<` and other XML (HTML) characters.
- start with ".rol" getting the `toString()` value.

Comment: I tried ${tempGebruiker.rol.name} but it did not seem to work. I did include a getter and setter, also a toString method in the Role bean.

Comment: can you post the details of the entity Rol

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<td>
${tempGebruiker.rol.name}
</td>
```

Comment: I tried ${tempGebruiker.rol.name} but it did not seem to work. I did include a getter and setter, also a toString method in the Role bean.